# Dropdown filter not working properly for Handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

i'm trying to filter my data in dropdown but on typing the exact value it is pointing to some other values and hides the exact value. not sure if i miss anything.

```
var container = document.getElementById('tblConfigurableDataTable');
 var hotConfigurableDataTable = new Handsontable(container, {
        data: parsedData,
        licenseKey: licenseKey,
        colHeaders: colHeaders,// ex. Name,Company...
        columns: columns,
        dataSchema: dataschema,// this is my list of data
        rowHeaders: true,
        headerTooltips: true,
        viewportColumnRenderingOffset: 100,
        width: $(window).width() - 120,
        height: height,
        contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below','remove_row', '---------', 'undo', 'redo', '---------', 'copy'],
        columnSorting: true,
        sortIndicator: true,
        filters: true,
        dropdownMenu: ['filter_by_condition', 'filter_action_bar'],      
        outsideClickDeselects: false,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        manualRowMove: true,
}
```

Comment: Can you use this fiddle and reproduce the problem there? https://jsfiddle.net/fg31chpL/

Comment: i have added my data here, please make last column as dropdown
https://jsfiddle.net/aq0d2o1r/1/

Comment: It is working fine in your fiddle.

Comment: After Adding "autocomplete" it worked fine for me.

Thanks :)